# Testing Stripe's webhooks - always an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm testing the web hooks in Stripe, I send an event from Stripe's website, here is my code:

```
require 'json'

class StripeWebHooksController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :webhook

  def webhook
    data_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(data_json['id'])
    #....
```

It always throws an exception:

`Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe::Event instance has invalid ID: nil)`

On Stripes's website it says the id is 00000 for some reason, whereas in production.log it's not zeros, it has a real id.

[image]

Here is the data from Stripe.com:

```
{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "charge.succeeded",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "api_version": "2015-02-10",
  "data": { # and so on....
```

And here's from production.log:

```
[- 8b95acf0-96ab-0132-4be7-42010af08843]   Parameters: {"id"=>"evt_15VG6eKl7JrIRpD6md9wpwUu", "created"=>1423721144, "livemode"=>false, "type"=>"invoice.created", "data"=>{"object"=>{"date"=>1423721144, "id"=>"in_15VG6eKl7JrIRpD6Nnd5hqm3", "period_start"=>1423721144, "period_end"=>1423721144, "lines"=>{"object"=>"list", "total_count"=>1, "has_more"=>false, "url"=>"/v1/invoices/in_15VG6eKl7JrIRpD6Nnd5hqm3/lines", "data"=>[{"id"=>"sub_5gdNIr16MzaeUe", "object"=>"line_item", "type"=>"subscription", "livemode"=>false, "amount"=>28000, "currency"=>"cad", "proration"=>false, "period"=>{"start"=>1423721144, "end"=>1426140344}, "subscription"=>nil, "quantity"=>1, "plan"=>{"interval"=>"month", "name"=>"accelerated_test", "created"=>1423705393, "amount"=>28000, "currency"=>"cad", "id"=>"accelerated_test", "object"=>"plan", "livemode"=>false, "interval_count"=>1, "trial_period_days"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}, "statement_descriptor"=>nil, "statement_description"=>nil}, "description"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}}]}, "subtotal"=>28000, "total"=>28000, "customer"=>"cus_5gdN3daWCJVNzg", "object"=>"invoice", "attempted"=>true, "closed"=>true, "forgiven"=>false, "paid"=>true, "livemode"=>false, "attempt_count"=>1, "amount_due"=>28000, "currency"=>"cad", "starting_balance"=>0, "ending_balance"=>0, "next_payment_attempt"=>nil, "webhooks_delivered_at"=>nil, "charge"=>"ch_15VG6eKl7JrIRpD6nHI4iIdx", "discount"=>nil, "application_fee"=>nil, "subscription"=>"sub_5gdNIr16MzaeUe", "tax_percent"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}, "statement_descriptor"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "receipt_number"=>nil, "statement_description"=>nil}}, "object"=>"event", "pending_webhooks"=>1, "request"=>"iar_5gdNTJThO2GckT", "api_version"=>"2014-11-20"}
```

Anyway, even if it's zeros, it doesn't have to raise an exception, does it? If it does, how do I test it after all?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the Test Webhook button is sending a *fake* event so you can't retrieve it through the API. You need to add some specific code so that when the event id is `"evt_00000000000000"` you don't call `Stripe::Event.retrieve(data_json['id'])`

If you want to test webhooks just create customers or charges in test mode in your account and events will be sent automatically.

Comment: But it says "Stripe::Event instance has invalid ID: nil", not "evt_00000000000000".

Comment: The correct error should be "Stripe::InvalidRequestError: No such event: evt_00000000000000"

Comment: Ok that error must be because you're parsing the parameters incorrectly here. I'd advise you to check what is in `request` first

Comment: Everything is correct `data_json['id']`, I checked it by pry-remote. However, sometimes it fails.

Comment: what can be in request if not the json generated by stripe having the correct structure?

Comment: I'm not sure here I mean maybe it's not `request.body.read` in your case so log the exact content of `request` and make sure you're reading the correct variable